# WordPress issue plugin creates specific URL but returns 404

Tags: php, wordpress

My uncle had hired a person to make a plugin for their site that adds kids to class lists (swimming etc). This was a few years back and the developer is no longer around.

The plugin works and from reading the code I see no problems. The issue lies in the fact that URL returns a 404. Specifically an action he registed.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url();?>/participant-pdf/?var=<?php echo $post_ID; ?>" style="color: #ffffff; display: inline-block; background: rgb(31, 68, 86) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; font-size: 13px; padding: 7px;" class="btn-generate-certificate" >Download PDF</a>
```

So specifically it's making a /participant-pdf/var?[id] link that this plugin would then trigger and create the PDF.

But I am now sure how routing works in WordPress and I can't track down the reason why the 404 happens. I was thinking of just putting the function in function.php and triggering it that way. But yeah, I am at a loss.

//edit adding action code

```
add_action('manage_particpant', 'Columns_content', 10, 2);
```

I do not see anything in settings > permalinks.

Comment: edit your question to add the code that handle this URL. have you activated the pretty URL in the admin -> "Settings" -> "Permalinks" ?

Comment: Added his action registration and I don't see the pretty url in permalinks - so guessing issue is there.

Comment: 1. check if your page "participant-pdf" working or not. 2. Then instead of query string use add_query_var. 3. Do not use word "var" in query string

Answer (score 0):

I think your slug URL "participant-pdf" does not exist in this plugin.